# Does independence of generators of σ -algebras imply the independence of σ -algebras? Without assuming that the generators are ∩-stable?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, independence

[If generators of $\sigma$-algebra independent, then $\sigma$-algebras are independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3448271/if-generators-of-sigma-algebra-independent-then-sigma-algebras-are-indepe) provides a proof that

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ be a probability space and $\mathcal{E}_i\subset \mathcal{A},\ \forall i\in I$. If $(\mathcal{E}_i \cup \{\emptyset\})$ is $\cap$-stable, then

$(\mathcal{E}_i)_{i\in I}\text{ independent} \Leftrightarrow\left (\sigma(\mathcal{E}_i)\right )_{i\in I}\text{ independent}$

holds.

But what happens if the generators $\mathcal{E}_i$ are not stable under intersections? (In other words: What happens if we do not assume that $\mathcal{E}_i$ are $\pi$-systems?)

Can you provide a counter-example in the case that $\mathcal{E}_i$ are not $\cap$-stable.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ be a Laplace model with $\Omega=\{0,1\}^3$ (e.g., 3 coin tosses), and $\mathcal{E}_1=\left\{\{\omega\in\Omega : \omega_1=\omega_2\}, \{\omega\in\Omega : \omega_2=\omega_3\}\right\}$, and $\mathcal{E}_2=\left\{\{\omega\in\Omega : \omega_1=\omega_3\}\right\}$. ($I={1,2}.)

Then
$(\mathcal{E}_i)_{i\in \{1,2\}}$ are independent, but $\left (\sigma(\mathcal{E}_i)\right )_{i\in \{1,2\}}$ are not independent.